# Google Maps devices with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es

I developed an android app with the google map API.

Everything was working fine, emulator and real device but some days ago the map is not showing anymore just **grey background and google logo in front**.

**I get this error:**

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports
 devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
```

I created a new emulator but nothing.

*Thank you!*

Comment: Even I also having same issue

Answer (score 0):

To use Google api, you need to use the **Google Api key**

When you do not use the key or your key is not correct, this problem is caused to you

[Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

### Update:

**Your application must use the OpenGL-ES 2.0 feature, use this code in your Manifest.xml :**

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Also If you use the emulator , enable the **Use Host GPU** Options from **AVD Manager** and then **Emulator Options** menu

Comment: My application was working well with a real and an emulator device. Api key was working and restricted for my package.

Comment: This problem usually occurs when the key is not set correctly in the [Google Admin Panel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) or has a typo problem.

Comment: This is not what the error description says. And it was working before!